# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'this.props.Name' as it is undefined. In ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Could you pleases helping me fix in this problem.

**TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 'this.props.Name' as it is undefined.**

[image]

src/component/Detail.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Character } from './Data_Character/Character';
import Total from './Total';

export default class Detail extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            names: Character
        }
    }
    render() {
        const { names } = this.state;
        return(
            <div>
                {names.map(name => (
                <Total key={name.id} Name={name} />
                ))};
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

src/component/Total.js file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Total extends Component {
    render() {
        const { id} = this.props.Name;
        return(
            <div>
                {id}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

src/App.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Footer from './component/Footer';
import Detail from './component/Page_ความเป็นมา/Detail';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* <Navbar /> */}
      {/* <Body /> */}
      <Detail />
      {/* <Detail_Home /> */}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a default value, or object, to destructure from `const { id } = this.props.Name || {};`.

This is even simpler if you convert your `Total` component to a functional component.

```
const Total = ({ Name: { id } = {} }) => <div>{id}</div>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely its because `Character` doesn't have an `id` field.

You are passing the contents of `Character` all the way through (via Name props), but the contents of Character must be omitting id.

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating through the data received from 'Character' object. To do what you do, check if your 'Character' object is in the below format

`Character = [{id: 'id1', name: 'Mark'}, {id: 'id2', name: 'John'}]`

Answer (score 0):

`Character` that you are importing in `Detail.js` must not having `id` as its property. Check that part or post Character's structure.